# How do I send HTTP request using ESP8266 to other port than 80?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, http, tcpip

I currently have a working connection to my ESP8266 module.

However, I can only connect to a server using the port 80, is it possible to choose a different port?

I can connect using `AT+CIPSTART="TCP","192.168.122.46",80`,
but I get an `ERROR CLOSED` when using `AT+CIPSTART="TCP","192.168.122.46",8090` for example

Also, how do I send an HTTP request using the `AT+CIPSEND`command?

**UPDATE:** Stupid me, it was just Firewall blocking it...

Comment: Are you certain there is a port open and listening on 8090 at the target machine, and it's bound to the right outward-facing interface?

Comment: It was just firewall blocking in